# Xcode 4.6 - "Valid signing identity not found" for Distribution provisioning profile

Tags: xcode, app-store, distribution, provisioning

I'm examining the process of submitting an app to the App Store and I'm having some kind of trouble here. I've been following [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/SubmitYourApp/SubmitYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH7-SW1).

I've created a Distribution Provisioning Profile, which I downloaded and added to Window - Organizer - Devices dragged in 'Provisioning Profiles' under the Library heading in the sidebar. What I see there is this:

[image: Here is an image of it.]

I've tried revoking all my certificates and adding them once again to my Keychain Access, but it didn't help. Even after refreshing the provisioning profiles in Xcode.

Also, I've read that this happens often if I change the machine I'm working on, but this is not my case. I've developed the app on the same Mac, I'm on right now.

I'm willing to provide more information to help reach to a solution to this problem if needed. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Make sure in Keychain Access that the certificate you are needing to use has the private key stored with it.
   [image: Keychain Access]
2. Make sure the bundle identifier matches EXACTLY with what you have for the AppID (unless you are using the Wildcard identifier)
3. Make sure the provisioning profile you selected uses the certificate created.
   [image: Provisioning Profile]
4. Make sure that you download that provisioning profile and are using that to sign the distribution settings of the target.

If all this is done, it should work fine.

Also, I gave a talk about certificates and provisioning for iOS.  [Here is a link](http://irockios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/iOS-Enterprise-Development-Keynote.pdf) to the keynote PDF which explains the process of how I do things.

Comment: I got it done. I found the answer in the very first step. I didn't have the private key for the distribution provisioning profile, so I asked the developer that originally created the certificate to provide me with the .p12 file I needed, and it worked out. Now I have a valid distribution provisioning profile. :)

Comment: Good deal.  Make sure to backup all your certs with the key (the p12 file).  Never know when a hard drive will fail.

Comment: Thanks a zillion for posting ElJay, you get a gold star.  Not sure how I did this, but #3 was my sticking point.  I ended up finding duplicate (to the naked eye) App IDs in the Provisioning Portal, switched to the other dupe and I was good.

Comment: It shows certificate in key chain access but not with private key. can you please help me this?

Comment: That means you didn't generate the certificate signing request (CSR) from that computer.  You will either need to get the p12 file (if one was exported from the computer that did generate the CSR or you will need to revoke the certificate from the developer portal and go through the cert process again.

Comment: This is a handy checklist for the whole cert/provisioning process. Thanks!

Comment: Can I just revoke and do the distribution profile all over again if I cannot get the p12 file?

Comment: Sure, but anyone that was using that cert for signing can never again use it.

Answer (score 3):

Just restart XCode.

Sometimes everything done through the documentation, but XCode does not work properly.

Comment: Sad, but true. Often, after making changes to the provisioning profile arcana, one has to restart Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for this. No telling how much time you saved me tonight.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck by this problem, try to do the whole process again.

Go to keychain, delete all the iPhone certificate and then do routine stuff. I faced this issue before for some reason, So I just redo it. Good thing is it won't take long time, just 5 mins : )

Hope this can help you.

Comment: can we do it in the case when you make a build and uploaded on appstore. now you want to upload an update and your provisioning profile is expired....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by opening the KeyChain Utility and deleting expired provisioning profiles. I updated my profile at members page of developers.apple.com following all the instructions.

Then opened up my application with Xcode 4.6 . Under Build Settings selected iPhone Developer with my name.

My issue was the old developer profile id and the new id were the same and I did not realize this. Removing the old one allowed the new to be used.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: I solved my latest run with this issue by simply choosing a Development profile and Identity and building and running and then switching back to the Distribution profile and Distribution Identity.

**Background**: 
My build was working last night, I switched to a different branch, tried signing the same way and it just continued to fail/say that there was no matching valid signing identity).

I tried restarting Xcode, restarting Mac, deleting invalid/expired profiles etc. Then just out of a need to test a run, I switched to the development profile (I am testing IAP with the Distribution profile), then when I switched back, it just worked!

One thing that is weird during this process is that the profile on the device does not seem to match the ones I have on disk, and during that process when I tried to add the one on disk to the device it was not highlighted as a valid selection (my dev one's were).

Even after running, the device still shows some different version of the same mobileprovision (different initial code and expiry is one day different than the one I have. I am working in a shared device environment so I don't have complete access/visibility to where these versions all came from).